# How to insert string into graphs in amchart

Tags: amcharts

I have a string variable `myGraph`:

```
newarr.push({"type": "smoothedLine", 
             "valueField": selected_ids1[i]});

var myGraph ='[' + newarr.map(JSON.stringify).join() + ']';
myGraph = myGraph.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

How i can insert this variable to amchart graphs

```
    var NewChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "startDuration": 0.4,
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "HH:mm:ss",
  "trendLines": [],
  "applyGapValue": 0,


  "graphs": myGraph.charAt,
  "guides": [],
    "categoryField": "date

",
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is not a lot to go from. Could you provide the full code for what you have so far?

Comment: @Darlesson thank you for responding. I added part of full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`graphs` is [an array](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#graphs) as outlined in the documentation. You can't assign a string directly to it. You need to parse the string back into an array:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  graphs: JSON.parse(myGraphs),
  // ...
});
```

I don't understand the reasoning behind why you went through the trouble of pushing items into `newArr` and stringify-ing it into a separate variable when you can simply just assign it directly anyway.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  graphs: newarr,
  // ...
});
```